# Google.cloud - module not found UNIX

Tags: python, unix, google-cloud-storage

I'm just trying to run `from google.cloud import storage`, but I get `ImportError: No module named google.cloud`.

I'm using python 3.7 and venv.
I installed `google-cloud-storage==1.27.0` on my venv and I'm still getting this error.
I'm using Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just reproduced your scenario and it did work for me. Starting from scratch, I did the following:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install google-cloud-storage
```

With this I created the virtual environment and installed the library `google-cloud-storage` and its dependencies, which include the libraries `google-api-core`, `google-cloud-code` and many more.

After that I can go into a python terminal (with the command `python`) and use `from google.cloud import storage` without a single issue.

Is it possible that you didn't activate the virtual environment?